# PHP MySQL insert query using $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

The variables are working; as I'm echoing them to the screen. But it's not inputting anything into the db/table. It's not telling me any error code, but it's failing. Let me know if you need any other information like the db_conn. I've tried several of the answers to similar questions and they're not fixing it for me. The form is up at [www.mommy-info.com/contact](http://www.mommy-info.com/contact). The second form on the page is the one I'm working with right now.

My form code:

```
<form action="/cq.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Username/Name</legend>
        <input
                placeholder="Insert your name"
                type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name"/>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Email</legend>
        <input id="email"
                type="email" name="email"
               placeholder="Insert your email address"/>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Question</legend>
        <textarea
                placeholder="Insert your question here."
                name="question"
                rows="5"
                cols="100">

        </textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

cq file

```
<?php
$ptitle = "Question Submitted";?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/head.php'; ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/navigation.php'; ?>
<?php
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$question = $_POST['question'];

$query = "INSERT INTO cq (user_name, email, question) VALUES ('$user_name','$email','$question')";
?>
<section class="content">
    <?php

    echo ($user_name);
    echo ($email);
    echo ($question);

    $result= mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);
    if($result){
        echo ('Your question was successfully submitted. You should receive an email
        response in 2-3 days');
    }
    else{
        echo  mysqli_error($db_conn) . '<br> Sorry, your question was not submitted. Please try again.';
    }
    mysqli_close($db_conn);
    ?>
</section>
<?php include ('footer.php');?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use prepared statements.

Comment: So you only get `Sorry, your question was not submitted. Please try again.`?

Comment: If you try running this exact query directly in mysql (with data rather than variables) does it work?

Comment: @chris85 Yes, I only get that statement.

Comment: @kojow7 yes, when I run INSERT INTO cq( user_name, email, question ) 
VALUES (
'user',  'email',  'question'
) it works.

Comment: @ethacker does mysqli_error($db_conn) return any error?

Comment: @YATO I don't think so, it returns "" by the looks of it.

Comment: Have a look at your source code as well and see if there is anything just before the `<br> Sorry ...`.

Comment: @kojow, it doesn't look like there's anything in the source code.

Comment: @kojow, I checked the db_conn and it's now failing too. (Yesterday I had it connecting.) I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: See www.mommy-info.com/sql.php : It's connected to the DB (says success) (I include this file so I can access the $db_conn. ) but when I try with the cq.php page it doesn't connect ( says fail).

Comment: I fixed it by putting the db_conn variables in the contact and cq.php pages. Is there a reason this doesn't work using the " php include"?

Comment: Where is your include and what is contained in the file you are including?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got similar problem back in my project.
Try to call the connection file directly in `cq.php`
then make you connection variable global.

Please include your connection file here for the review.

```
<?php
$ptitle = "Question Submitted";?>
 <?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/head.php'; ?>
<?php require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/navigation.php'; ?>
<?php
$user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$question = $_POST['question'];

$query = "INSERT INTO cq (user_name,email,question) VALUES ('".$user_name."','".$email."','".$question."')";


require_once('your/path/connection_file_name.php');
global $db_conn;
echo '<section class="content">';
$result= mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);
    if($result){
        echo ('Your question was successfully submitted. You should receive an email
        response in 2-3 days');
    }
    else{
        echo  mysqli_error($db_conn) . '<br> Sorry, your question was not submitted. Please try again.';
    }
    mysqli_close($db_conn);
    echo '</section>';
    ?>
   <?php include ('footer.php');?>
```

Try in **else** just for debugging

```
<?php if($result){
        echo ('Your question was successfully submitted. You should receive an email
        response in 2-3 days');
    }
    else{
        echo 'MySql Error:'.mysqli_error($connect);
    } ?>
```